# SystemJS Builder: minify html and css during build

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, gulp, systemjs

I'm learning how to use `SystemJS Builder 0.15.30` to bundle my `Angular 2 rc.6` application written in `typescript 2`. I use `gulp 3.9.1` for building:

Each component in my application has 5 files:

- component.ts
- component.html
- component.scss
- component.css (generated by gulp task #1 below)
- component.min.html (generated by gulp task #2 below)

The `.ts` imports the `.min.html` and `.css` to be used inline.  My objective is to minify and bundle these in one step, instead of having to generate them first.

I currently have 3 gulp tasks that I'd like to merge into one:

**1.** Scan all folders; transpile `.scss` to minified `.css` in same directory

```
gulp.task('build-css', function () {
    gulp.src(appDev + '**/*.scss', {base: "./"})
        .pipe(postcss([precss, autoprefixer, cssnano]))
        .pipe(ext_replace('.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

**2.** Scan all folders; minify `.html` and rename result to `.min.html`

```
gulp.task('shrink-html',function(){
    return gulp.src(appDev+'**/*.html', {base: "./"})
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(ext_replace('.min.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

I first run these tasks. Once they produce the `.css` and `.min.html` respectively, I run a typescript compiler task that turns the `.ts` to `.js`.

**3** finally I run the SystemJS Builder task. I use `buildStatic` to create a self-executable bundle:

```
// build-ts is run before this, to compile typescript into JS
// and move everything out to the production folder (appProd)
gulp.task('bundle',['build-ts'], function() {
    var builder = new Builder('', './systemjs.config.js');

    return builder
        .buildStatic(appProd + '/main.js', appProd + '/bundle.js')
});
```

I know there must be a way to minify during the `buildStatic()` so I won't need to generate all these useless `.css` and `.min.html` files.

**My best effort**: I can hook into the files as they are processed, using [the `fetch` option](https://github.com/systemjs/builder#overriding-fetch):

```
gulp.task('bundle',['build-ts'], function() {
    var builder = new Builder('', './systemjs.config.js');

    return builder
        .buildStatic(appProd + '/main.js', appProd + '/bundle.js', 
        {
            fetch: function (file, fetch) {
                if(file.name.search(/\/app.*\.html$/)!==-1){
                    console.log('html: '+ file.name);
                    //how to manipulate content and return minified HTML string?
                    return fetch(file);
                }else if (file.name.search(/\/app.*\.scss$/)!==-1){
                    console.log('scss: '+ file.name);
                    //how to manipulate content and return minified CSS string?
                    return fetch(file);
                }else{
                    return fetch(file);
                }                
            }
        });
});
```

The file names I want to minify get printed to the console, and I know that `fetch(file)` will give me their content but how to process the content and return a minified string?

PS: [Cross-posted on github](https://github.com/systemjs/builder/issues/690)